# Tomcat JNDI Bean

Tags: java, tomcat, jndi

I'd like to know if is possible to store an object with data into a JNDI resource, like we can do in sessions, to share the data (login data) between different applications. I've read the doc in http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html but I'm still a bit confused due to the instantiation process of the JNDI. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[Tomcat's JNDI service](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html) is very lightweight, and intentionally provides isolation between webapps. The implementation also does *not* support remote connections and references, etc. So you won’t be able to share data between servers in a cluster.

If you don't want to use a fully-featured [Jakarta EE](https://jakarta.ee/) container (like [Eclipse Glassfish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GlassFish) or [Wildfly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WildFly)) then you might want to look into something like webcache to share data like this.